# How to load rules from a string in Drools 6.5

Tags: java, drools, kie

I have a set of rules in the form of a String that are passed as an argument to my function, which is not stored in any file. From what I read  so far, there are many solutions to this for versions before 6, where I am guessing APIs were very different. (They suggest using KnowledgeBase, which is deprecated in 6.5)

This is my solution so far:

```
KieFileSystem kfs = kService.newKieFileSystem();
Resource drlResource = ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(rules.getBytes());
drlResource.setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL);
kfs.write(drlResource);
KieBuilder builder = kService.newKieBuilder(kfs).buildAll();
```

But when I run, this is throwing an error saying:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource does not have neither a source nor a target path. Impossible to add it to the bundle. Please set either the source or target name of the resource before adding it.ByteArrayResource[bytes=[105, 109, 112, 111, 114, 116, 32, 106, 97, 118, ...], encoding=null]
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieFileSystemImpl.write(KieFileSystemImpl.java:95)
```

But I do not have a source file here, how can I convert a String into a rules resource?

I am using Drools 6.5.0.Final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use this:

```
String drl = "...";
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
kfs.write( "src/main/resources/simple.drl",
    kieServices.getResources().newReaderResource( new StringReader(drl) ) );
KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();
```

It's right there in the Drools API - one just has to find it.

**Edit**
Javadoc has an index where you can look up method and type names. The interfaces are

```
org.kie.api.KieServices 
org.kie.api.builder.KieFileSystem
org.kie.api.io.KieResources
org.kie.api.io.Resource
```

Javadoc: "The KieFileSystem is an in-memory file system used to ..." To see how it works, look at the source code.

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't find this. Will the `kfs.write()` create a temporary file in that location? How does it work?

Comment: I am not using maven, instead of "src/main/resources/simple.drl" , if I am using "src/main/rules/abc.drl" (any user defined path) , is it a correct syntax? In my case it is not throwing any error, on the contrary its not even executing the rules. I am stuck in the problem, please help.

Comment: @NamrataChoudhary Comments aren't meant for asking new questions. Show rules and Java code in a question of your own.

Comment: You can find the complete working project in the following url https://github.com/pandiyan90/spring-boot-drools

Comment: @laune i discovered that the rule is created in-memory. Is there any way i can get it out into a file ?

Answer (score 2):

Hidden in  the Drools code on GitHub there is a simple example which also shows you how to do this - it helped me to get it working:
[KieFileSystem example on GitHub](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/master/drools-examples-api/kiefilesystem-example/src/main/java/org/drools/example/api/kiefilesystem/KieFileSystemExample.java)

Answer (score 0):

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
        KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
        kSession.insert(createCommlObject());
```

If you do a buildAll() as mentioned in Laune's answer, kie module will load all .drl files. If you want to load the .drl file of your choice then use

```
 KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("Rules.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);
```