# Drools - rule from string gets created in-memory

Tags: drools

Hello fellow droolers !!

I am experimenting with the api mentioned referenced below to load rules from a string.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927331/how-to-load-rules-from-a-string-in-drools-6-5
```

However, i observed that it gets created in-memory, and is not written to a file on my hard disk.

Is there an api to get such a behaviour ?

Cheers!

Comment: Why would it write to your hard disk? Did you try adding logic to write to your hard-disk? The API is to read a String-based rule into memory.

Comment: Well, i want to be able to dynamically add, edit the rule. And also persist the rules for displaying in UI.

Comment: I mean, that's ... fine. But that's a different use case than the one in the linked question (which is also for a much older version of Drools.) Have you read the Drools documentation for the current version of Drools? Have you tried just saving your new rule to the local filesystem and loading from there (or to a database or rest service)?

Comment: @Roddy, that's a good idea. I think DB approach is better for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drools API solves different problems than creating resources on OS file system.

> KIE virtual file system KieFileSystem to build the project

[drools documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.38.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/)

> KieFileSystem is an in-memory file system provided by the framework

[baeldung tutorials](https://www.baeldung.com/drools)

Comment: That does not answer my question. It is a repitition of what i mentioned earlier.

Comment: This is short explanation with links to documentation what API is supposed to do and what it is not supposed to do.